# Comparing two dataframes with identical shape and iterate over rows calculating the pct_change of df1 - line1 to df2 - line1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a problem calculating the difference (in %) for two dataframes which have an identical shape (datetimeindex + columns 0-2000). I would like to compare the values of the rows of df1 with the rows of d2 (df1 line1 with df2 line1, df1 line2 with df2 line2 etc.) and calculate the difference between the two values and store the result in a new dataframe. I want to compare the values columnwise that fall into the same time (e.g. 12:01) but the dataframes have values from different days (time is the same).

These are sample dataframes:

df1

```
                       A       B       
time      
2019-04-20 12:01       12     0.5      
2019-04-20 12:02       14      1      
2019-04-20 12:03       15     0.2     
2019-04-20 12:04       18      5       
2019-04-20 12:05       9       6
```

df2:

```
                       A       B       
time      
2019-04-21 12:01       10     0.5      
2019-04-21 12:02       11     1.5    
2019-04-21 12:03        5      4      
2019-04-21 12:04       20      3       
2019-04-21 12:05        3      6
```

expected output:

```
             A          B       
time      
12:01       -16.67       0      
12:02       -21.43      50     
12:03       -66.67    1900     
12:04        11.11     -40       
12:05       -66.67       0
```

As a first step I already tried pandas merge and join functions but they do not give me the desired output.

I then tried to write a function:

```
def merge_calculate(df1, df2):

    if len(df1) == len(df2):
    return(((df2.values - df1.values)/df1.values)*100) #df1.values = start value, df2.values = end value
```

The function gives me an array but I am not sure if the calculation was done in the way I wanted.

I'm grateful for any input! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
diff = -(df1.values - df2.values)/df1.values*100
date_time = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for d in list(df1.index)]
time = [dt.datetime.time(d) for d in date_time]
df3=pd.DataFrame(data=diff,columns=df1.columns,index=time)
```

Explaination:

- `diff` is the comparison between df1 and df2, and it is a 2-d numpy array
- You need to assign index and columns for diff, in order to make it a dataframe:
- `data=diff` assigns data for the dataframe
- `columns` simply equals to `columns=df1.columns`
- `index=time` is the `time` you extracted from `datetime`

`print (df3)` gives you the output:

```
                 A       B
    12:01:00 -16.666667    -0.0
    12:02:00 -21.428571    50.0
    12:03:00 -66.666667  1900.0
    12:04:00  11.111111   -40.0
    12:05:00 -66.666667    -0.0
```